How can I display the name of my generic type T in the documentation of a class which instantiates a generic interface?
My problem is that I have a generic interface in my C# .Net WPF project and I want my XML documentation to display the chosen Type to be displayed in the class that implements the interface.
This is the definition of my generic interface
   public interface ICreate<T> 
   {
        /// <summary>
        /// Function to prepare and open a new <see cref="Window"/> either to create or edit a <see cref="T"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="New">Determines if the form to open should be in creation (<see langword="true"/>) or edition (<see langword="false"/>) mode </param>
        /// <returns><see cref="CurrentWindow">CurrentWindow</see></returns>
      Window SetupWindow(bool New);
   }

And the implementation is done like this :
public class SubscriptionViewModel : CCOMGenericViewModel, ICreate<Subscription>, IUpdate, IDelete
{
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public Window SetupWindow(bool New)
        {
            CurrentWindow = new MyWindow();
            SubscriptionForm subscriptionForm = new SubscriptionForm(Mode)
            {
                DataContext = this
            };
            CurrentWindow.Content = subscriptionForm;
            CurrentWindow.Show();
            return CurrentWindow;
        }
}

Which shows me this : Function to prepare and open a new Window either to create or edit a T
when I would like it to be : Function to prepare and open a new Window either to create or edit a Subscription 
